# How to whitelist an URL in Privoxy (with a little regexp)

Tags: privoxy

how can i whitelist these URLs in Privoxy?

```
http://foo.org/user/10000/track?page=1
http://foo.org/user/10000/track?page=2
http://foo.org/user/10000/track?page=3
http://foo.org/user/10000/track?page=4
...
```

I don't want to whitelist "foo.org" i just need to whitelist these specific url's.
the "page=NUMBER" where NUMBER=1..99999999 [so it's a big number, i don't know exactly how much]
What do i need to write in the "user.action" file? :\

Comment: Why in earth was this question downvoted..?

Answer (score 3):

```
http://foo.org/user/10000/track\?page=[0-9]+
```

Should work

Answer (score 1):

this should work, unless you need it to be more specific

```
{-block -filter}
foo.org/user/10000/track\?page
```